# How to load javascript src file into new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I can open a new tab with content using `window.open()` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dXvt/

But how can I load a javascript file (script tag with src attribute) in the new tab? I want the resulting html of the tab to look like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <script src="http://www.example.com/example.js"></script>
      <p>Your content here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To add the code directly into the "toNewWindow" div tag does not work because it of course immediately loads the js file in the original tab..

Thanks!

Comment: I dont really think its a duplicate , because I need a solution for an empty tab which I created e.g. via window.open(..)

Comment: I found an easy solution now:
var w = window.open(),
theDoc = w.document,
theScript = document.createElement('script');
theScript.type = "text/javascript";
theScript.src = "http://www.example.com/example.js"; theDoc.body.appendChild(theScript);